How to use SDKMAN tools in a Kubuntu 24.04 linux box like SDKMAN gradle or groovy for instance to be used in desktop operations
Hi I have installed SDKMAN for JDK purpose, but found other tools like Gradle & Groovy.
I want to use them in my gradle & groovy operations in my Kubuntu 24.04 laptop. What is the Linux Command to make SDKMAN Gradle & Groovy be recognized in my Kubuntu 24.04 Laptop without any security threats.Is there a way.
